# Minimum of $\left(\frac{1+\sin^2x}{\sin^2x}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1+\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}\right)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I would like to find the minimum of
>
> $$f(x)=\left(\frac{1+\sin^2x}{\sin^2x}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1+\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}\right)^n,$$
>
> where $n$ is a natural number.

I know there is possible by derivate, but

$$f'(x)=n \left(\left(\cos ^2(x)+1\right) \sec ^2(x)\right)^{n-1} \left(2 \left(\cos ^2(x)+1\right)\tan (x) \sec ^2(x)-2 \tan (x)\right)+n \left(\left(\sin ^2(x)+1\right) \csc^2(x)\right)^{n-1} \left(2 \cot (x)-2 \left(\sin ^2(x)+1\right) \cot (x) \csc^2(x)\right).$$

I think this is not the best way.

Comment: You're probably right. But there is a way without using calculus. You should only use Cauchy's inequality:

$$ \frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\geq \sqrt{a_1a_2}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably right. But there is a way without using calculus. You should only use Cauchy's inequality:

$$ \frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\geq \sqrt{a_1a_2}.$$

---

$$ \left(\frac{1+\sin^2x}{\sin^2x}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1+\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\right)^n+\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)^n \geq \\  \geq 2\left(\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)}\right)^n=2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}+\frac{1}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}}\right)^n= \\ = 2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}}\right)^n=2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{8}{\sin^22x}}\right)^n\geq 2\left(\sqrt{1+8}\right)^n=2\cdot3^n$$

We must now prove there is $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)=2\cdot3^n$.

---

To that end, notice that $f(x)=2\cdot3^n$ is equivalent to following system

\begin{cases}
\sin^2x=\cos^2x, \\
\sin^22x=1, 
\end{cases}

which has $x_1=\pi/4$ as solution. Now note that

$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\left(\frac{1+1/2}{1/2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1+1/2}{1/2}\right)^n=2\cdot3^n.$$

---

Thereby, the minimum value of $f(x)$ is

> $$f_{min}=2\cdot3^n.$$

Comment: ooh!  Thank you for your solution. Do you think it's possible to do this by derivative?

Comment: @Ryany I think so, but I'm in between two positions at the moment.  I will try it as soon as possible but it might take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Using A.M $\geq G.M.$ on the first and second inequalities yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &=\left(\csc ^{2} x+1\right)^{n}+\left(\sec ^{2} x+1\right)^{n} \\
& \geqslant 2 \sqrt{\left[\left(\csc ^{2} x+1\right)\left(\sec ^{2} x+1\right)\right]^{n}} \\
&=2\left[\left(2+\cot ^{2} x\right)\left(2+\tan ^{2} x\right)\right]^{\frac{n}{2}} \\
&=2\left(4+2 \cot ^{2} x+2 \tan ^{2} x+1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}} \\
& \geqslant 2\left(4+2 \cdot 2 \sqrt{\cot ^{2} x \tan ^{2} x}+1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}} \\
&=2\cdot 9^{\frac{n}{2}} \\
&=2\cdot 3^{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
$\therefore f(x)$ attains its minimum value $2 \cdot 3^{n}$ when $$\cot ^{2} x=\tan ^{2} x \textrm{ and } \csc^2 x=sec^2 x\Leftrightarrow x=\pm \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \dfrac{1+\sin^2x}{\sin^2x}, B = \dfrac{1+\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}$. Then $A+B = 2+\dfrac{1^2}{\sin^2x}+\dfrac{1^2}{\cos^2x}\ge 2+\dfrac{(1+1)^2}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}=6$. Thus: $A^n+B^n\ge \dfrac{(A+B)^n}{2^{n-1}}= \dfrac{6^n}{2^{n-1}}=2\cdot 3^n$. Equality occurs when $\sin x = \cos x$ or $x = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$.